# Transferring existing applications from one domain to another in Openshift v3+

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-client-tools

How to transfer existing applications from one domain to another domain in openshift version 3+.

I am looking for a consolidated solution instead of pointing remote repository to new domain in git because there are so many developers working individually thus so many local repositories.

Solution described here won't work for me (reason above) - [Openshift transfer app from one domain to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963335/openshift-transfer-app-from-one-domain-to-another)

There was a command `oo-admin-move`  in version-2, is there an alternative in version 3+ ?

Or please suggest any other solution to try out.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is a little confusing so can you clarify. Are you wanting to change the domain name used in the Git repositories URLs of all the build configurations, or are you want to change the domain used in the routes for exposed URLs a site is made available as outside of the cluster? The ``oo-admin-move`` command looks to be a tool for moving applications between nodes in a cluster which is a different thing again.

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton, Lets just say I want to clone all existing apps deployed on one openshift cluster to newly installed openshift cluster on a new host. Thanks. -

Comment: I would start by reading here: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/latest/admin_guide/backup_restore.html#project-backup

Comment: This should resolve my problem. Backup & restore is the key.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.